# Executing Commands to a Process

Tags: java, process, runtime

So I have this code:

```
String[] command = new String[] { "java", "-jar", file.getName() };
try {
    System.out.println("Loading input/output");
    final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    final OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream());
    final BufferedReader consolein = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Loaded input/output");
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("hi");
                try {
                    String temp = consolein.readLine();
                    out.write(temp);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I am trying to execute commands the the running jar. Input is fine, I see all of the messages in console. I added the "hi" message to test if it was working. It shows up whenever I input something. However, whatever I type is NOT being sent to the running program. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried adding a new line to the end of the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what the process you are calling is expecting you may not need a newline; you may just need to call `flush()` on the `OutputStreamWriter` out.

```
String temp = consolein.readLine();
out.write(temp);    
out.flush();
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test.  I wrote this little program which is to be run by my other class...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RunMe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You said: " + text);
        System.out.println("Bye!");
    }

}
```

The I wrote this to run it...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class Runner {

    private static BufferedReader br;
    private static BufferedWriter bw;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "RunMe.jar");
        pb.redirectError();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            Process p = pb.start();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        String text = null;
                        while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(text);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();

            String text = scanner.nextLine();
            bw.write(text);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();

            p.waitFor();

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {
                bw.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And it outputted...

```
Hello world
This is a test
You said: This is a test
Bye!
```

(The second line is what I typed in, the third line is out put from the `RunMe` class).

So I would suggest you need to send a new line.  You could try using `\n`, but it's probably better to use the `line.separator` property